# EF 5 load data async in .net 4

Tags: c#, telerik, task-parallel-library, entity-framework-5

I need to load some data from DB but because i need to load all of it my windows screen (Windows form) is freezing so i try it with this code:

```
var data = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                repository = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ILibriRepository>();
                librat = repository.GetAll().ToList();//

            });
data.ContinueWith((a) =>
{
    librat.ForEach(c => lvLista.Items.Add(new LibraListViewItem(c)));
}, CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None, uiScheduler);
```

but even this when the data is loaded and need to render in the ListView the screen is freezing.

Comment: How many items are you adding? For how long is the screen freezing? Are you sure the code in the continuation is causing that?

Comment: about 1000 rows render takes for 20 sec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 20 second delay is probably not occuring while the query is running, but as a result of adding all of the items to the list view (which has to happen on the UI thread).

Here's some thing that might help:

In your ContinueWith, call `ListView.BeginUpdate()` before you start your loop, and call `ListView.EndUpdate()` when you are finished.

This will prevent the list from trying to redraw itself for every item that you add to it.